# Why rich:modalPanel styleclass styles not being applied to it?

Tags: css, richfaces

I have a `rich:modalPanel` which I am styling from external css,
But the problem is the `styleClass` attribute does not apply my style to my `rich:modalPanel`.
I tried to put input text element inside then call a specific class in my extrernal css but it is working fine.
Additionally the `headerClass` attribute is not working also.

what am i missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you used Firebug on Firefox to see what your HTML is being rendered as?

Are there any inline styles being applied?

What CSS styles are being applied to the modalPanel?

In your CSS you could try adding `!important` after the rules for modalPanel to see if its a specificity issue.

Comment: I think the !important is useful..I do some firebug and it works now. Thnx.